# Add third level menu on wordpress

Tags: menus

I would like to add a third level menu on WordPress. This is the code I've added to the functions.php file to create the secondary menu, but when trying to repeat the same code with a third menu, I get an error.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_menus' );
  function my_custom_menus() {
     register_nav_menus(
        array(
  'primary-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
  'secondary-menu' => __( 'Secondary Menu' )
```

Comment: Do you see this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/132155/9884

Answer (score 1):

Add a new item to the array like displayed below:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_menus' );
  function my_custom_menus() {
     register_nav_menus(
        array(
        'primary-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
        'secondary-menu' => __( 'Secondary Menu' ),
        'third-menu' => __( 'Third Menu' )
        ));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've tried to do so, it's giving me an error.

Comment: Than you are having problems somewhere else. if you post what's an error maybe you will get more help. Are you sure you are not duplicating function name?

Comment: @Ethan31 What kind of "Error"? Errors have messages, which provide the needed information to help you.